# Proving that a basis multiplied by an invertible matrix is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> $B = (v_1 , v_2,\ldots, v_n)$ form a basis of a general vector space. Given $P$, an invertible matrix, prove that BP is a basis.

Here's my thought - we know that an invertible matrix is a product of multiplying elementary matrices. Meaning, for each $v_i$, multiplying it with $P$ will result in some elementary actions done to the vector. These actions are simply linear combinations of them - so, BP will be a basis with vectors that are all linear combinations of vectors in $B$, meaning, they will still span and be linear independent.

Is this direction correct? I'll formalize it, ofcourse, but wanted opinions.
Thanks!

Comment: In “Linear combinations of them” what does “them” refer to? If it’s the rows of $B$, then how do you know that all of these linear combinations of the rows are linearly independent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider a linear combination of $BP$ that is zero:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_kPv_k = 0.$$

Because $P$ is invertible, you may apply $P^{-1}$ to both sides.
Do you think you can finish?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I think I got it.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped.